# ¿Como funciona spl_autoload_register()?

Tags: php

He estado leyendo pero no me queda claro de que forma carga en automático los archivos.
Mi pregunta seria si las carga todas o va cargando conforma se vayan requiriendo en la aplicación.

Answer (score 3):

Es la función que se ejecuta antes de mostrar un error de tipo Undefinded Class. Es decir, si dentro de tu App llamas a una clase que no la incluiste con anterioridad ya sea con Include o Require, antes de mostrar un Fatal Error se ejecuta la función del spl_autoload_register, que en mi caso se encarga de buscar un archivo con el mismo nombre que la clase e incluirlo para así evitar errores. Es la base de los Autoloaders.

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
        $appPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'App';

if (file_exists($appPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class . '.php')) {
    include_once($appPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class . '.php');
}
```

});